# Why can I not import csv file into my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 on the my server, and I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[rptost]
(
    [ID_ost] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [id_rpt_ost] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_rptost_q] [int] NOT NULL,
    [usrid] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [Confirm_id] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [date_] [int] NOT NULL,
    [time_] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_create] [int] NOT NULL,
    [time_create] [int] NOT NULL,
    [date_read] [int] NOT NULL,
    [time_read] [int] NOT NULL,
    [usrid_create] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sycl] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [report_type] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [activity_no] [int] NOT NULL,
    [tedad] [int] NOT NULL,
    [price_sycl] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [zarib] [int] NOT NULL,
    [price_year] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [price_moavaq] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [price_recoverable] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [price_nonrecoverable] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [effect_company] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [effect_subcrib] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [result_] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Financial_] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [id_incom] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id_risk] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [desc_] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [desc_analyz] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [desc_modify] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [desc_action] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [desc_return] [nvarchar](max) NULL
)
```

I run this query on the server:

```
select top 5 * from rptost
```

and right click on the result and save into server desktop, that server SQL Server collation is this:

```
Polish_100_BIN
```

On the other side, I have SLQ Server 2014 on my client pc, I want import that csv file into my client database with sql server import wizard, but I get this error in import wizard:

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "x29" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

How can I solve that problem? Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Hard to tell because we'd need to know which column `x29` is in your csv file.

Comment: @Filburt ok my friend,please wait to say you

Comment: تور العملها,.تهیه کتابچه ی مدونی  @Filburt this is that x29

Comment: In cases like this, I create an error output for any lines that fail to import. Just save your Import Task as an SSIS package and open it to edit an include an error output file.

Comment: @Filburt this error:<outputColumn
                      refId="Package\Data Flow Task 1\Source - 5_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Error Output].Columns[ErrorCode]"
                      dataType="i4"
                      lineageId="Package\Data Flow Task 1\Source - 5_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Error Output].Columns[ErrorCode]"
                      name="ErrorCode"
                      specialFlags="1" />

Comment: It looks like you only included the `ErrorCode` column. Please include all columns in the error output mapping to identify the row that causes the error.